# how a owner of website charges for website after deployment

Tags: web, owner

My teacher gave me an assignment. its a scenario "assume you have developed a school management system. After deploying you charge money for each entry of student in database. suppose 2$ per student.how the owner of website generates bill for the principal of school"

Answer (score 0):

You have all student entry in your database so you can create report based on database data like you can export database data to excel or csv file.
Otherwise select students by query for last month or last 15 days and export query result to excel or csv file.you can send this generated file to principal so he can view how many students enrolled and how much he has to pay to owner.